# Best practices for handling bounced member emails in Buddypress?

Tags: wordpress, email, buddypress

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this one.

We are running a mildly busy WP/Buddypress site. We have an issue with members registering, and confirming their emails. Then something will go wrong with their email address. From then onward, ever activity, every message, everything that user does, generates a bounced mail. Multiply that by a few hundred thousand members, and that's a lot of bouncing mails filling up our inboxes.

At the moment, I am pointing those member emails to a black hole address, and messaging them in an attempt to get them to sort their emails out. But that is quite time consuming, and many users just carry on regardless.

We are about to add a real time email verification to the registration. This will help a bit. But it won't help for users who's emails hit problems after they have registered.

Whenever I've built systems sending out mails to users, I've always included a 'dead mail' function on user accounts, to deal with this very situation. I thought this was common practice, but maybe not.

I have already posted on the Buddypress forum, with no response. I've scoured the web looking for solutions, but can find nothing relevant.

If anyone has experience with this, or has some ideas about how best to handle this, your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for advise on how you should react when emails bounce(stop sending them emails, disable the user, ...), or how to differentiate bounce types? The latter can be quite hard, and I believe you should probably look for a service to do it if you want certainty.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. No, I am looking for the best practice for dealing with user emails within WP that are bouncing. That is, to deal with them at the WP end, and not send any further mails to that user / email. Disabling the user is a bit extreme, some of these users are our long term customers just having problems with their email. See we can't mail them to let them know obviously. And we can't message them because their accounts will be deactivated. There must be a better way than just kicking customers off the site?

Comment: I can't say anything regarding implementation in WP, hopefully others can, but I run a fairly large site, and I've opted for a) showing clearly visible messages "hey, we couldn't email you, is your email still up to date?", and for non-permanent ("mailbox full", "MX temporarily down"), I'm increasing the intervals that messages may be sent, and quickly, think 1 week => 1 month => 3 month => a year, which keeps the accounts "alive", but looks less spammy. Permanent errors get a "don't send any email" flag until the user changes the address.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back. Yes that is how I would usually do it on non-wp sites. And that seems the logical way to do it. It's why I am surprised that it doesn't already do this or have a plugin for it. I'm wondering what other people do. I'm assuming you wrote your own plugin or code to do those bits?

Comment: Yes, I did, but my site ran ( and still runs, I have to admit) on mostly plain CGI (with a few APIs in the backend), so there was no other option available. I suppose that most WP community admins run small communities and don't know (or worry) about that, and the larger ones start to switch away from WP at some point. Definitely hoping for other opinions as well, it is an interesting topic.

Comment: Yes I would be interested in other ideas too. :) While we are waiting for anyone else to post - I think you're right about people moving away from WP at the first chance. I've worked in dev for over 15 years, and people have been raving about how amazing WP is so I thought I would try it out on a project with some flesh. As a standalone blog/cms for small basic sites, yes it's a very elegant piece of dev. However, on the plugins side, I am amazed at how mature the WP arena isn't. So many fundamentally necessary addons are missing. And my God, plugin support is appalling across the board.

Comment: It is very approachable for non-IT people, and it's nice for quickly getting a site up and running, and allows quite a few hacks, but yeah, I see it mostly for small sites & shops that you move away from if the site starts to be your main job. I do work on larger client sites, but those stay WP because of "it works OK, why spend money", not because "it's great, why change".